# Creating New Button

Tags: android, android-button, android-context

I am having a problem with an Android program I'm working on. The method below is in MyActivity. MyActivity has an inner class InnerClass which extends AsyncTask. In the doInBackground method of InnerClass i search a database. The result of that search is passed to this method processSearchResult. Everything works except the very last line throws a NullPointerException. I tried using getApplicationContext() in place of this while creating the button and it still threw the exception. I debugged it and found the problem is in the android.content.ContextWrapper class. In the getApplicationContext() method is a call mBase.getApplicationContext. The problem is that the variable mBase is null. When using the this keyword there is still a call to this method and mBase is still null. Can anyone tell me why mBase is null? Or if its actually normal for mBase to be null?

```
public void processSearchResult(ResultSet result) {
    try {

    int x = 1;
    while (result.next()) {

        String name = result.getString(1);
        String ing = result.getString(2);
        String ins = result.getString(3);
        String notes = result.getString(4);
        String type = result.getString(5);
        String course = result.getString(6);

        Recipe r = new Recipe(name, ing, ins, notes, type, course);
        recipeList.add(r);

        Button button = new Button(this);
```

Comment: mBase?. Where is mBase in the code?.

Comment: mBase is in the android.content.ContextWrapper class as stated above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't update the user interface from the `doInBackground` method of the `AsyncTask` you need to `publishProgress` and update it from the `onProgressUpdate` method instead.

**How do I publish my progress from `doInBackground`**

```
publishProgress(0); //Assuming progress is 0
```

**Where do I update the UI from then?**

```
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress){
    //HERE
}
```

**this** may not refer to what you're thinking.
What I do is keep a private global `Context` variable in my code for future reference as in:

```
private Context x = this;
```

Answer (score 1):

this should be your activity's context, and not application context. Try MyActivity.this.

Answer (score 1):

To create button you should use `ActivityContext`, try

```
Button button = new Button(MyActivity.this);
```